# At what speed am I walking?

Tags: pokemon-go

Yesterday I found an egg and put it in my incubator, and was hoping that my egg will be hatched this morning after my daily train ride. Unfortunately, the app did not mark this period as walking. I read somewhere that there is a speed-limit to determine if you are walking or driving by car for example. At what speed do I have to bike to mark this as walking?

Answer (score 6):

If it's the same as ingress it should be around 30km/h.

Although there is not any info on it on the support page, so it's only speculation for now.

Comment: They have never officially announced it for Ingress but the community found it out to be around 30 km/h by field trials.

Comment: Ingress' 30km/h is the speed at which Ingress speedlocks. I'm rather confident that Pokemon does not consider walking to be the equivalent of 18 MPH