# Does walking fast prevent eggs hatching?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a couple of eggs that I've picked up from some Pokestops (I'm lucky enough to live above one).

I walk a lot. I get to work through a 2 mile walk / train journey every day, so I should be picking up loads of steps for the eggs I have. However, because I'm normally always running late... for everything, I have to rush everywhere, so I walk at an above average pace.

Today I've walked around 5 miles, but the game has registered 100 metres. Is this because I walk too fast, or because of something else?

It's worth pointing out that I have the app open when walking... mostly because I have to catch them all. (This made me miss a train this morning... luckily I was early :D)

Comment: The speed limit where things broke down in Ingress was around 30kph, so probably not.

Comment: @Studoku Pokemon Go doesn't have a speedlock. I somewhat doubt that it would consider everything under 30kph as walking.

Comment: [You need to have your app open](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222049967-Incubators-and-hatching-Pok%C3%A9mon-Eggs-), to register your walking distance.

Comment: Thanks @gre_gor, but it was :/

Comment: @KazWolfe So you're saying I could get on a train and hatch all my eggs? And you know this for a fact? Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @Studoku No, I'm saying that the speed for walking should probably be far below 30 km/h. I'd guess anything less than 10 km/h would count for walking, but I have no authoritative data or personal experience that would allow this to be a good answer.

Comment: @KazWolfe Did anyone say it only counted walking or should only count walking? Running and cycling to hatch eggs are a part of pokemon games.

Comment: @Studoku I know for a fact that it doesn't count cycling, at least in the beta. Running I could not test properly.

Comment: @KazWolfe Which would contradict your earlier comment about there being no speedlock.

Comment: @Studoku Allow me to clarify. There is no speedlock for *game actions*. You can spin Pokestops and catch all you want no matter the speed. Walking to hatch eggs, however, does have a max speed.

Comment: There is no need for rudeness. The game is new, and we're all trying to figure it out together.

Comment: @Joe did your phone go into power save mode (e.g. screen actually off, not just Pokemon's "battery saver")? If so, that will stop progress.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [At what speed am I walking?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272688/at-what-speed-am-i-walking)

Comment: @galacticninja Why should this be the duplicate instead of the other way around? This question & answer seems to be better worded & more popular than tha one you've linked.

Comment: @Robotnik The question I linked to meets the criteria suggested by the top-voted answer in the meta post, [On ending Chronological Oppression with respect to the matter of Question Duplication](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8190/4797) - i.e. it first had a definitively upvoted answer.

Comment: @Joe too bad you missed the train. Did you try a cruveball?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Based upon my time playing Ingress (created by the same company and also using a lot of the same infrastructure it seems), you can go at least 15 mph (~24km/h) and it SHOULD still track you. (This is a little less than the 30 kph someone in the comments mentioned).

Note that 15 mph is a 4 minute mile (or 2.5 minutes per kilometer). This is a little slower than the record running speed, and still over the average biking speed.

It also doesn't tend to lock you until you've made multiple jumps at faster speeds, and it only does so to stop spoofers.

Therefore I doubt it is your walking speed.

If your game isn't registering your distance, I would assume it is either GPS troubles, the game in general, or server issues. The majority of this is handled by Niantic and will likely improve as the game progresses. Unfortunately, that means there is probably little you can do other than contact Niantic to let them know.

Comment: You're right. I definitely don't walk that fast:) I think this is the best answer I can really hope for at this point.

Comment: Can confirm that at approximately 30kmph, you do not register on Pokemon Go. Your character moves around the map, but it will no grab locations or spawn pokemon, and the distance does not contribute towards eggs.

Comment: @Timelord64 - Likewise, cruising at 20km/h while my friend holds both phones we were able to find Pokemon & hit Pokespots with relative ease. Anything higher than 25 it started to jump around.

Comment: I can hit them going in a car even at 50 mph, but it stops counting for my eggs far before that.

Comment: The mechanic (at least in Ingress) relied on a "circle of valid movement" over your first registered position via your device's GPS.  Your next GPS "ping" would check if the position was inside this circle of valid movement.  If it was then the distance between your first and second ping was recorded and the "circle" would move not to your new position but at a fixed speed in the direction you are travelling.  P-GO I hear takes into account in built pedometer/accelerometer but have not got any technical confirmation.  Let me know if you want gifs explaining the Ingress movement mechanics.

Comment: My backroad drive testing (with passenger) showed that 15 mph(24 kph) worked but 20 mph(32 kph) did not

Answer (score 4):

I went for a 5km run and it only tracked a little over a 1.5km.  Had the app open the whole time and slowed down or stopped several times to catch pokemon. I dont know if the stopping threw the tracking off or the changing of speeds.  I'm hoping it just a bug in the game right now and will be fixed, because I would prefer to go for my daily runs and catch pokemon than have to walk the whole time.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed earlier as I was walking, it stopped showing my character walking. I just closed the app and reopened. Perhaps that could be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Saw a video where someone said the max speed allowed is about 8km/hr which is about 5 mph. Which is about the pace of speed walking. However My brother said 20 mph which means you could probably ride a bike and you should be fine.

I was driving a car in city around 30mph and it did not count the distance towards my egg hatching. GPS tracking also does matter for this. Servers could also be an issue. The PokemonGo app MUST be ON to while walking/jogging/running/biking/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten the impression but have not run tests to check, egg hatching is faster when you walk/jog in a straight line.  For instance was walking around in a cemetery taking lots of turns and retracing my route and it wasn't counting efficiently, but when I walked from one end of Main Street to the other it got that.

Answer (score 0):

The max speed the game works at and max speed to which the tracker works are different. I've kind of noticed about 5-10 mph being the max register for walking (incubation).

Comment: Do you have a source, or possibly some research to share?

Answer (score -2):

Were you walking neer a road at any time? I have noticed wether it's car,bike or walking, it dos t like to register if your character is on a road"past the white outline" if I hold my phone against the window in the car it registers off the road sometimes and my distance increased greatly, the. If I'm walking on a sidewalk and my character is on the road it won't register or barely at all.

Comment: This is a good theory !